# Issue in using Replace function for Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, replace

I just tried to replace the [2,3]th element of a matrix with 100, but it replaces [3,2]th element:

[image: image1]

and when I tried to change the [3,2]th element it changes the [1,1]th element:

[image: image2]

How can I solve this?

Comment: You are replacing the value 7 with 100, check `A[2,3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are replacing the index 7 with 100 as

```
A[2, 3] 
#[1] 7
```

Instead we can use the row/column indexing

```
replace(A, cbind(2,3), 100)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4
#[2,]    5    6  100    8
#[3,]    9   10   11   12
#[4,]   13   14   15   16
```

#### data

```
A <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4, byrow=TRUE)
```